# Reference a repeater within a gridview on item databound

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagrid, repeater

I've got an `asp:DataGrid` which has an `asp:Gridview` within it and this has many nested `asp:Repeater`'s within that and i'm trying to reference the nested repeater from within my `OnItemDataBound` function

My code is similar to this

```
<asp:Datagrid runat="server" id="DataGrid1" OnItemDataBound="ItemDB" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Gridlines="None">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <p>Test</p>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:Datagrid>
```

bit complicated but that's kinda what i'm working with.

In my `ItemDB` command I have this

```
Sub ItemDB(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs)

    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then


        If CType(e.Item.FindControl("GridView1"), GridView).Visible = True Then
            CType(e.Item.FindControl("Repeater"), GridView).Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

but i get the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

and i'm guessing it's because i am referencing a Repeater within a GridView

Any ideas how to reference this properly?

This code may not be the simplest way of doing this but i've taken over someone else's work and need a quick fix before re-coding it all

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to find the Gridview in the template and then register the event for it's RowDataBound, and the find the repeater in the event handler.  You should use the OnItemCreated Event to register the OnItemDataBound events, but the easiest would be to indicate the methods in your .aspx:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat=""server"
                                     onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <p>Test</p>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

and in your code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //you could find the repeater in the gridview's itemtemplate here
    // to the BulletedList
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Repeater rpt = (Repeater)e.Row.FindControl("Repeater1");
        rpt.Visible = false;

    }
}
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
         //you could find controls in the repeater's itemtemplate here.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far - how do I the reference something within my `DataGrid` once i'm in the `GridView` rowdatabound function?

Comment: Added an example in the GridView1_RowDataBound eventhandler above